# Change ComboBox Color of the Drop Down Button

Tags: excel, vba

Im actually working on a VBA Excel Project. We have some requirements for the Color style of the whole sheet.

I designed a UserForm and it was possible to change all colors, except from the Drop Down Button of the ComboBox.

With these commands i can set the colors of Foreground, Background and Border:

```
Controls("ComboBox1").ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Controls("ComboBox1").BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Controls("ComboBox1").BorderColor = RGB(160, 131, 101)
```

But i am not able to change the Drop Down button itself.. I searched a while but cant find anything..
[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to change this? Or is it set by Windows and not possible to change? Like this it looks a little ugly..
Thanks in Adance & best regards